# Building array in increments less than 1 - Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to build an array in incremental steps. I'm guessing there must be a function analogous to matlab's vector building, e.g. vector(1:0.1:2) which builds a vector and fills it with values from 1 to 2 in 0.1 steps. Is there a way to do this in fortran?

Comment: Explain more what you mean. Maybe use an example.

Comment: For example, I'm trying to build an array containing values between 5 and 20 incremented in steps of 0.2 instead of integer values, i.e. an array with values of 5, 5.2, 5.4..... 19.6, 19.8, 20. I'm guessing their has to be some sort of do loop involved, but I'm not exactly sure how to make a do loop iterate itself in steps less than 1...

Comment: Edit your question with the array example. The array is enough, avoid conplicated verbal explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array constructor as shown in the following code:

```
program main
  implicit none
  real,allocatable,dimension(:) :: vec
  real                          :: a,inc
  integer                       :: n ,i
  a = 1.    ! initial value
  inc = 0.1 ! increment value
  n = 11    ! number of values  
  allocate(vec(n))
  vec = [(a + (i-1) * inc, i=1,n)]  ! array constructor
  write(*,'(11f7.2)') vec
end program main
```

out:

```
1.00   1.10   1.20   1.30   1.40   1.50   1.60   1.70   1.80   1.90   2.00
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Quick question, I wrote a piece using this as a basis, but now I'm trying to write the results to a file. However, it won't seem to let me do that; is there a way to format the allocated array so that I may put the results in a file to be read from later?

Comment: If you have another specific problem, you can open a new question with the code and the description of the error.