# Fortran Array Splice Initialization

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to initialize an array with equal spacing between 0 and 1 in fortran.
My code is :

```
program test
  double precision :: h
  double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: x

  h = 1./11
  if(.not. allocated(x)) allocate(x(10))

  x(1:10) = [h:(1-h):h] (*)
end program
```

The error I am given is "The highest data type rank permitted is INTEGER(KIND=8)" at the stared line.
I've tried to change it with

```
x(1:10) = h:(1-h):h
x = h:(1-h):h
x(1:10) = (/(h:(1-h):h)/)
```

and various other forms with no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building array in increments less than 1 - Fortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709403/building-array-in-increments-less-than-1-fortran)

Comment: Also note that `h=1./11` has a different result from the `h=1d0/11` which you may prefer.

Comment: If you're trying to learn fortran, I would try to stay away from implied do loops. They are unnecessary and sometimes difficult for beginners to grasp. I recommend a complete do loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're using is not valid Fortran and implied DO loops can't have non-integer bounds. You want something like this:

```
x = h * real([(i,i=1,size(x))],kind(h))
```

For more information, look up "array constructors" in the standard or a textbook.

Don't use `(1:10)` on the left side - see https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this

Comment: Using `size(x)` as the upper bound on the implied-do prevents one taking full advantage on automatic allocation on assignment.  Some may say this is a good thing.

Comment: If you want to point to a local resource, we have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/996/arrays/6858/array-constructors#t=201701312332014110052).

Comment: I get your point about use of size(x), though that's fine in the example provided. Yeah, if you want to be able to assign arbitrary size arrays to the allocatable array, you wouldn't want to make it depend on the current size.

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
[h:(1-h):h]
```

is, from a Fortran point of view, broken.  It looks a bit like an array slice, but that would require integers, not reals, and `(` and `)` rather than the `[` and `]`.  And it looks a bit like an array constructor, for which `[` and `]` are correct, but `h:(1-h):h` isn't.

Try this

```
x = REAL([(ix,ix=1,10)],real64)/11
```

(having declared `ix` to be an integer).  The expression `(ix,ix=1,10)` is an *implied do-loop* and, inside the `[` and `]` produces an array with integers from `1` to `10`.  I trust the rest is obvious.

Incidentally, since the lhs of my suggested replacement is the whole of `x` you don't actually need to explicitly allocate it, Fortran will automatically do that for you.  This is one of the differences between a whole array section, such as your `x(1:10)` and the whole array, `x`.

And if that doesn't produce the results you want let us know.

Comment: I see Mark and I are on the same page here - his response came in while I was composing mine. The only thing I would object to is the use of "real64" here. That's a constant from ISO_FORTRAN_ENV and may or may not be the correct value, depending on other factors. Using KIND(h), as I had it, is better.